# Ошибка импорта модуля librosa в python 3.9.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио

Есть кусок кода на Python для загрузки библиотек для анализа аудиоданных:

```
import librosa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import os
from PIL import Image
import pathlib
import csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
import keras
from keras import layers
from keras import layers
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

После установки модуля librosa (pip install librosa) импорт все равно ругается на этот модуль.

Comment: Проверьте, может вы назвали этот файл `librosa.py`?

Comment: Я могу установить OpenCV как `pip install opencv-python`, а подключать я его буду как `import cv2`. Librosa точно подключается как `import librosa`?

Comment: Файл называется по-другому

Comment: Да, подключается как import librosa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у тебя установлено несколько версий Python, то в Path переменных среды в свойствах компьютера строка версии, на которой работаешь, должна стоять выше остальных.
После этото провести pip istall librosa